# problem when read a buffer from bufferreader scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a snipest of scala code that read files from google storage and do some opertation with BufferReader:

```
   val path_gs = new Path("gs://bucket")
   val filename= "filename.txt"
   val fs = path_gs.getFileSystem(new Configuration())
   val dataInputStream: FSDataInputStream = fs.open(new Path(filename))
   val inpuSteam=new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream, "UTF-8")
   val br=new BufferedReader(inpuSteam)
   var buffer = Array.ofDim[Char](300)

   var j=0
   while ({j=br.read(buffer); j} > 0) {
    val str = new String(buffer,0,j)
    println(j,"##", str)
}
```

the output of this code:

```
   (300,##,textxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtx............................)
   (300,##,textxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtx............................)
   (300,##,textxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtx............................)
   .
   .
   (92,##, textxtx xtxtxt ...) //contain only 92 chars
   (300,##,textxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtx............................)
   (300,##,textxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtx............................)
   (300,##,textxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtx............................)
   (46,##,tetetete..) \\ contain only 46 chars
   (300,##,textxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtx............................)
   (300,##,textxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtx............................)
    .
    .
```

The problem is the buffer in some cases read 300 chars , in other cases read a number of chars !=300
how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code